# Highcharts - colorByPoint for serie.scatter.marker

Tags: highcharts, scatter

In Highchart I would get a series of colored points séquencielle way:

marker 1: green,
marker 2: blue,
marker 3: red,
marker 4: green,
marker 5: blue,
marker 6: red,
marker 7: green,
marker 8: blue,
marker 9: red,
etc.

This is exactly what is achieved for columns with chart.options.plotOptions.column.colorByPoint = true

How to get the same thing for Scatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use colorByPoint in scatter series as well. To have only three colors in your scatter series you need to update the colors array in Highcharts object:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue'],
    series: [{
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [
        [161.2, 51.6],
        [167.5, 59.0],
        [159.5, 49.2],
        [157.0, 63.0],
        [155.8, 53.6],
        [170.0, 59.0],
        [159.1, 47.6],
        [166.0, 69.8],
        [176.2, 66.8],
        [160.2, 75.2],
        [172.5, 55.2],
        [170.9, 54.2],
        [172.9, 62.5],
        [153.4, 42.0],
        [160.0, 50.0]
      ]
    }]
});
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/22419j0j/

Comment: Yes, thanks! and it surprised me! (Parameter not in highshart API reference ...)
But I forgot to mention that I use Highstock. Does it make a difference?

Comment: You're right, it works. Thank you very much. I have yet to identify what the problem was in my own testing. But it works now.